# one_to_many association through a join table

Tags: ruby, many-to-many, one-to-many, sequel

I'm trying to do a one_to_many association through a join table.

I have `Orders` with a `cart_id` field pointing to a `Cart`, which has no relevant keys. In the `CartItem` table there's a `cart_id` pointing to the cart. Poring through the documentation, I see how to implement the case where the `Cart` has a `order_id` column, the `many_to_many` association but not for the other way around. `many_to_many` seems to expect the left key to be in the join table. And `one_to_many` seems to not allow the use of a join table at all. Or maybe I'm just missing something?

Answer (score 0):

After getting on IRC with Jeremy Evans, he said I should use the following options on a `many_to_many`.

```
:left_primary_key=>:cart_id, :left_key=>:id, :right_key=>:id, :right_primary_key=>:cart_id
```